# How to get current date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, datetime, .net-3.5, date

How to get current date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format in ASP.NET ?

Comment: How to get the current date for what? What are you using the date for will you be displaying it. Is it just for one field or multiple fields. It would be a good idea to elaborate a little more.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Which WebControl are you using? Did you try?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: leave off the semicolon for VB.NET ;)

Comment: if anyone need some more references i suggest to read and follow the tips over here : http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format-vbnet

Answer (score 7):

The `ToString` method on the `DateTime` struct can take a format parameter:

```
var dateAsString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
// dateAsString = "2011-02-17"
```

Documentation for [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4) format strings is available on MSDN.

Answer (score 6):

`<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>`

Answer (score 4):

try ToString method for your desirer format use

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

OR you can use it with your variable of DateTime type

```
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

where dt is a DateTime variable

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

Might be worthwhile using the CultureInfo to apply DateTime formatting throughout the website. Insteado f running around formatting whever you have to.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns( ...
```

or

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Code should go somewhere in your Global.asax file

```
protected void Application_Start(){ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var formatedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

To ensure the user's local settings don't affect it