# How to format display of datetime in asp.net, bootstrap datepicker as dd/MM/yyyy?

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I have a c# class with `datetime` field.

```
public class User
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

And this date is displayed in the next format:
 `2019-04-11T00:00:00Z`
How can I format this displayed date to `dd/MM/yyy` without converting to string?

Maybe I should use attributes?

I display this date in BootstrapDatepicker

Comment: How would you display a date without converting to a string?

Comment: I do not convert this date.
This format comes from SQL server

Comment: where / how are you displaying that date? asp.net sites? wpf? forms? uwp? This is a "How to display X in Y" problem - what is Y?

Comment: @PatrickArtner asp.net, bootstrap datepicker

Comment: [edit] your question and put it in there, thanks.

Comment: [how-to-get-current-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029333/how-to-get-current-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-in-asp-net)

Comment: [custom-date-format-for-bootstrap-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896176/custom-date-format-for-bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Date Format for Bootstrap-DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896176/custom-date-format-for-bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I format this displayed date to dd/MM/yyy without converting
> to string?

I think you misunderstand some basic thing.

Format concept *only* applies when you try to get *textaual* (aka `string`) representation of a `DateTime` instance. A `DateTime` instance does *not* have any implicit format. It just have date and time values and it is a `long` number which is based on [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8).

Since you keep it as a string, you need to parse it to `DateTime` first, then you need to use `DateTime.ToString` method to generate *proper* format (with proper culture settings of course).

For example;

```
Console.WriteLine(myUser.BirthDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

> This format comes from SQL server

If you keep this as a `string` in your database, **don't**. You need to use `datetime` (or better `datetime2`) type. You should always choose the right data type for your values in your database.

Further reading: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: while true - this does not answer the "how to display datetime" part of this question.

Comment: _"Format concept only applies when you try to get textual (aka string) representation of a DateTime instance."_ - well, not only `DateTime`, but yes, that's correct.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I mentioned that on _Since you keep it as a string, you need to parse it to DateTime first, then you need to use DateTime.ToString method to generate proper format (with proper culture settings of course)._ But I added an example as well.

Comment: @SᴇM Yes, the "format" concept is mentions with `string` as a general concept, it is not a special thing for `DateTime` struct.

Comment: He has a DateTime from his SQL, he displays the user, the birthday is presented in a Bootstrap.DatePicker with defaultformat, he wants to show it as custom format ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner This is not something that I can answer, only OP can.